# Angular returning promise after completion of flow

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've a controller, where the flow should go sequentially. I'm making an $http GET request, and it should wait for getting the response and then it should go forward. Rather it completes the flow, and at the end it gets the response. How can I stop it?

Here is the code

```
function CarouselDemoCtrl($scope,$http) {
    $scope.slides = [];
    console.log("1")
    $http.get('data.json').
       then(function(response) {
       $scope.slides = response.data.slides;
       console.log("done");
    });
    console.log("2");
}
```

It prints "1,2 and then "done". Where it should follow as "1,done and 2"

The code snippet is like this

```
  function CarouselDemoCtrl($scope,$http) {
    $scope.slides = [];
    console.log("1");
    $http.get('data.json').
      then(function(response) {
       $scope.slides = response.data.slides;
      console.log("done");
    });


    $scope.myInterval = 7000;

    console.log($scope.slides);

   var i, first = [],second, third;
   var many = 1;

   //##################################################    
//Need to be changed to update the carousel since the resolution changed
$scope.displayMode = "tablet";
//##################################################
if ($scope.displayMode == "mobile") {many = 1;}
else if ($scope.displayMode == "tablet") {many = 2;} 
else {many = 3;}
for (i = 0; i < $scope.slides.length; i += many) {
  second = {
    image1: $scope.slides[i]
  };

  if (many == 1) {}
  if ($scope.slides[i + 1] && (many == 2 || many == 3)) {
       second.image2 = $scope.slides[i + 1];

      }
      if ($scope.slides[i + (many - 1)] && many == 3) {
        second.image3 = $scope.slides[i + 2];
     }
     first.push(second);
   }
    $scope.groupedSlides = first;
}
```

Comment: It should print 1,2 and then indeed done. A promise is asynchronously executed  code while you expect it to be run synchronously.

Comment: Put your `2` into the `.then` callback...!? This is how asynchronous execution works. You can work *with* it, you can't work against it.

Comment: @deceze thanks for your input. But however thats my scenario. How can I fix my issue?

Comment: You can't. This code is not going to work as you expect, period. Use the callback Luke, use the callback!

Comment: Because I'm going to use "$scope.slides" after $http gets response. As the response is not yet received, I'm getting null value in it.

Comment: Use. The. Callback. That's what it's for.

Comment: You can resolve a promise before a view is shown... no callback needed.

Comment: Can you please provide me an example?

Comment: Simply put whatever code you want to execute **inside `.then` after `console.log('done')`.** It's that simple.

Comment: You can for example use the resolve functionality in ui-router. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki This is basically what you need.

Comment: Ah.. I got your point.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print `2` after the `done` then you need for your api call to finish. You can detect that when control comes to the `then` callback. Thus you will have to print `2` inside your success callback.

```
function CarouselDemoCtrl($scope,$http) {
$scope.slides = [];
console.log("1")
$http.get('data.json').
   then(function(response) {
   $scope.slides = response.data.slides;
   console.log("done");
   //calling it after the done
   console.log("2");
});
```

}

Comment: No. I want it outside itself. Because outside the $http call back, I'm using $scope.slides. There its coming as null as still the response is not yet received.

Comment: That is not possible my friend. this is what asynchronous behaviour is.

Comment: I understood Ashfaq. But, that's my scenario.